# Is it possible to set Wordpress as Back-End for a static Website?

Tags: wordpress

I have a static website and I want to make it dynamic. But client say that they want to integrate this website to wordpress with It control panel. So, My question is that, Can I integrate a static website to wordpress and Can I make It`s control panel in wordpress?

The website`s link is below..

http://greenopia.in/wip/Dkreate/

Answer (score 0):

yes, every customization is possible in wordpress. if you static site has some page , you can first save those page data into wordpress page. Then fetch from there.

But firest step is to convert your site html to wordpress theme. Refer [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html-creating-template-files--wp-33939) to know about wordpress theme development.

Comment: Hey, do you know any free HTML to Word-Press Theme converter?@Arka

Comment: I dont know which is useless also.

Comment: I know http://wpsiteconvertor.com/ has a program to convert website to wordpress theme, but I haven't found any free programs that do that.